# Use desktop webinspector to clear cache in mobile safari?

Tags: iphone, safari, mobile-safari, web-inspector

Is it possible to clear mobile safari cache using the desktop web inspector in Safari?

I know I can go to the settings in the iphone, but it's a bit of a hazzle and since the phone already is teathered to the computer while debugging, it would be really nice if I could clear it thourgh the webinspector in safari.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `Cmd + Option + R` while in the developer tools web inspector to force mobile safari to reload its cache.

I had another problem which was that Fiddler also has a cache. I also had to clear that as I was running the iPad through the fiddler proxy.

Once I cleared the fiddler cache, and then used `Cmd + Option + R`, I could see the iPad requesting and receiving the new files.

Comment: This doesn't work what-so-ever iOS 9.3, OSX 10.11.3, Safari OSX 9.0.3.  That's after having chosen both "Disable Caches" and "Empty Caches" in DevTools. That didn't work so I tried Shift+Cmd+R, the page reloaded but it still used the cached file. I ended up having to rename the file to get iOS 9.3 Safari to use the new file. Maybe it works for the .html file but it didn't work for scripts.

Comment: This shortcut does a "Reload Page From Origin", which doesn't purge or clear the cache at all. It loads resources without ever using cached resources, as if there was nothing in the cache.

Comment: Doesn't work most of the time for me. At the very least, it still loads large png files from cache. Only solution I've found is to "Clear History and Website Data". This is madness.

Comment: For whatever reason, the shortcut option+command+r works for me instead.

Comment: These shortcuts do not work. Easier to use an Incognito window. Not as convenient, but works.

Answer (score 28):

I came across this issue with safari 11.1, and the answer was really simple. There is actually a button on the right top corner of the network tab to disable caching when debugging. I thought about leaving this just in case someone else miss the button just like I did. ( the one in blue )

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this affect normal desktop Safari behavior (When the Web Inspector is not open)? Does this setting persist?

Comment: Hmmm I think is not persisting, so is should only be applied if the inspector is open

Comment: This does nothing for the mobile device.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Safari 11.1 on a macbook, and using Web Inspector connected to an iPhone with iOs 11.2.6.

From the Web Inspector, if I use the key board short cut: OPTION + COMMAND + R, it both clears the cache and reloads the page.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there is an option for this in the Develop menu - however it doesn't appear to work.

A simple way around this is to add a new parameter to your url
eg. http://domain.com/testing.html?refresh=1

*(of course having the functionality working in Web Inspector would be better)*

Answer (score 1):

Old thread but if you have your iphone connected to your desktop developer tools, you can hit OPTION + CMD + E (shortcut for empty caches) while viewing the web inspector that is connected to the iphone. Then hit the refresh button in your iphone browser.

Make sure you are really connected (Develop > Your Phone Name > The Website being viewed on phone) It should show on your desktop developer tools dropdown menu.

Safari 11.1 
High Sierra
ios 11.4

Answer (score 1):

Try Cmd+alt+R when iPhone is connected and your inspecting with developer mode. It worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

Nothing here worked for me on iOs 11.4.1. After digging around in the network tab I found `Command + K` which is "Clear Network Items". I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I think this just clears the list of items in the Network tab. Like the list itself, not the items from the cache.

Answer (score -2):

You can connect your iPhone to a MacBook via USB and use the [Safari Web Inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26014850/debugging-mobile-safari-in-ios-8-and-ios-9)
Once you are connected, you can use **Develop** -> **Empty Caches**.

Comment: This does not affect the cache of any attached device that is being inspected.. It only affects the caches used by Mac Safari.