# How to view traffic requests on mobile Safari on iPhone

Tags: ios, macos, debugging, safari, mobile-safari

I am trying visualize the network traffic in a waterfall or other model on my iPhone something similar to https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Instruments/Instruments.html. I am able to do it just fine in chrome with Android - https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

I am on Safari 8 and Mac 10.10 and it is possible to inspect my safari's traffic following [Debugging mobile Safari in iOS 8 and iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26014850/is-it-possible-to-debug-mobile-safari-in-ios-8)

I am also able to see network traffic but I am not able to see individual network requests. (see screenshot)[image]
I opened Develop-> My phone-> tab-> Network -> Timelines

Also I am able to see network traffic from normal desktop. 
[image]

is there anything I am missing or is it just something apple hasn't shipped?